# Is there an advantage to installing an ArcGIS web adaptor in the DMZ

Tags: security, arcgis-portal, arcgis-web-adaptor

I'm trying to architect a new ArcGIS Portal site. I see ESRI has instructions on configuring a reverse proxy to work with a web adapter installed on the network. However I have also seen sources talking about installing the web adapter directly on a DMZ web server and registering it with a portal on the network. Is there an advantage to doing it this way?